# shower install schluter & go boards

Tags: shower, install

Using a schluter pan and go boards for the walls . what do I use to water proof between the pan and the resting go board on top of the pan .

Answer (score 1):

The pan and walls are sealed with thinset and the [Schluter band](https://www.flooranddecor.com/shower-systems-installation-materials/schluter-kerdi-band-waterproofing-strip-951500192.html?utm_content=M-Shopping&utm_term=&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAwvKtBhDrARIsAJj-kThfzovIO7Yq0tV4HySMesU8QyLZksY22O5VmQ1srZiHihQvoQeLA4kaAnFdEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

There are many videos out that show tips and how-to on application of Schluter products.